# Invoking node js callbacks asynchronously

Tags: javascript, callback

Consider this code snippet:

I invoke the `callback` from the function `dothis`. Notice the `callback` in `dothis` is inside a  `timeout`

```
console.log("start");

doThis(":)", callback)

function callback(a) {
      console.log('in callback '+ a)
    }


function doThis(a,cb) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb(a)
      }, 2000);

      console.log('in first function') 
    }
console.log("end")
```

I get the following result:

```
start
in first function
end
in callback :)
```

Now consider the below,

Everything is the same except that this time there's no `timeout`:

```
console.log("start");

doThis(":)", callback)

function callback(a) {
  console.log('in callback '+ a)
}


function doThis(a,cb) {
    cb(a);
 console.log('in first function') 
}
console.log("end")
```

I get the following result:

```
start
in callback :)
in first function
end
```

1. It is said that a callback in JavaScript can be invoked
   asynchronously or synchronously. How do you know that it is invoked
   in either of those ways?
2. The `timeout` seems to show the expected asynchronous behaviour. Without the timeout, my code behaves like the callback is invoked synchronously as per the logged messages. My understanding of run-to-completion semantics have me thinking that I should always get the first result no matter how long it takes to process the callback. My understanding is that JavaScript executes the current activity(JavaScript code) to the end and any asynchronous activity (callback) is queued (in the event queue) for later execution.

In this case it seems that if the result from the callback is ready, it is logged before the following messages. When it is delayed, it is logged last. Is this asynchronous behaviour?

Comment: You misunderstand the situation. Callbacks are not always queued. They are just functions, like `console.log()` and run when you call them. In async code the thing that changes is when they are called —  they are called after some async activity like a timeout.

Comment: That makes sense, since on using a timeout of 0 milliseconds, it still showed asynchronous behaviour

Comment: These async activities eg timeout, how are they implemented? Do they uses promises? Also does it mean that a callback can only be asynchronous when it is called after an asynchronous activity like Ajax? Every asynchronous callback example I come across always talks about Ajax requests.

Comment: You can't really make custom functions that add to the callback queue (well maybe with a node extension), they are implemented as part of the node environment. This is a good expiation: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 0):

Considering this section of your code:

```
console.log("start");

doThis(":)", callback)

function callback(a) {
    console.log('in callback '+ a)
}

function doThis(a,cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(a)
      }, 2000);

    console.log('in first function') 
}

console.log("end")
```

You have `doThis` that it's a function that calls the callback function inside, but the stack waits and executes the second function after it call the `callback(a)`, maybe you expect that the code executes everything in order but the trick here is that the execution stack call the first function (`doThis`) but waiting for the timer.